# how to Configure WordPress with another database?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, wordpress, web-hosting

As WordPress uses a **wp-config** file for connecting with the main database, and usually the database server is hosted on the same platform. But I want to use a third-party service or database provided by another hosting platform.

For example,

The website is **hosted** on **Siteground** and it will use **database** services from **Bluehost**.

I have tried this by setting all the details in **wp-config** file,

- dbname
- username
- Password etc.

but I'm facing **Error Connecting With Database**. Could you please suggest to me, Is it possible with WordPress or what are the other ways?

Comment: The `DB_HOST` parameter specifies the host for the database which is either an IP or a FQDN. You might need to configure firewall rules, however

Comment: You need to make sure that external connections are allowed/possible to the new database server, which is normally _not the case_, at least not by default.

Comment: You also need to keep in mind that this will (almost) always cause performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is associated with firewall or some rules that needs to modify.

Comment: It's not something silly like you're trying to connect WordPress to SQL Server is it? You *have* tagged [tag:sql-server] after all. WordPress doesn't natively support SQL Server.